# Decoupling non-serializable object to avoid Serialization error in Spark

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

The following class contains the main function which tries to read from Elasticsearch and prints the documents returned:

```
object TopicApp extends Serializable {

  def run() {

    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val sparkConf = new Configuration()
    sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
    sparkConf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer","256")

    val es = new EsContext(sparkConf)
    val esConf = new Configuration()
    esConf.set("es.nodes","localhost")
    esConf.set("es.port","9200")
    esConf.set("es.resource", "temp_index/some_doc")
    esConf.set("es.query", "?q=*:*")
    esConf.set("es.fields", "_score,_id")

    val documents = es.documents(esConf)
    documents.foreach(println)

    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("Total time: " + (end-start) + " ms")

    es.shutdown()

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    run()
  }

}
```

Following class converts the returned document to JSON using `org.json4s`

```
class EsContext(sparkConf:HadoopConfig) extends SparkBase {
  private val sc = createSCLocal("ElasticContext", sparkConf)

  def documentsAsJson(esConf:HadoopConfig):RDD[String] = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val source = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
      esConf,
      classOf[EsInputFormat[Text, MapWritable]],
      classOf[Text],
      classOf[MapWritable]
    )
    val docs = source.map(
      hit => {
        val doc = Map("ident" -> hit._1.toString) ++ mwToMap(hit._2)
        write(doc)
      }
    )
    docs
  }

  def shutdown() = sc.stop()

  // mwToMap() converts MapWritable to Map

}
```

Following class creates the local `SparkContext` for the application:

```
trait SparkBase extends Serializable {
  protected def createSCLocal(name:String, config:HadoopConfig):SparkContext = {
    val iterator = config.iterator()
    for (prop <- iterator) {
      val k = prop.getKey
      val v = prop.getValue
      if (k.startsWith("spark."))
        System.setProperty(k, v)
    }
    val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime
    runtime.gc()

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("local[2]")

    conf.setAppName(name)
    conf.set("spark.serializer", classOf[KryoSerializer].getName)

    conf.set("spark.ui.port", "0")

    new SparkContext(conf)
  }
}
```

When I run `TopicApp` I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
    at TopicApp.EsContext.documents(EsContext.scala:51)
    at TopicApp.TopicApp$.run(TopicApp.scala:28)
    at TopicApp.TopicApp$.main(TopicApp.scala:39)
    at TopicApp.TopicApp.main(TopicApp.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@14f70e7d)
    - field (class: TopicApp.EsContext, name: sc, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class TopicApp.EsContext, TopicApp.EsContext@2cf77cdc)
    - field (class: TopicApp.EsContext$$anonfun$documents$1, name: $outer, type: class TopicApp.EsContext)
    - object (class TopicApp.EsContext$$anonfun$documents$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    ... 13 more
```

Going through other posts that cover similar issue there were mostly recommending making the classes `Serializable` or try to separate the non-serializable objects from the classes.

From the error that I got I inferred that `SparkContext` i.e. `sc` is non-serializable as SparkContext is not a serializable class.

How should I decouple SparkContext, so that the applications runs correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your program to be sure, but the general rule is not to create anonymous functions that refer to members of unserializable classes if they have to be executed on the RDD's data. In your case:

- `EsContext` has a val of type `SparkContext`, which is (intentionally) not serializable
- In the anonymous function passed to `RDD.map` in `EsContext.documentsAsJson`, you call another function of this `EsContext` instance (`mwToMap`) which forces Spark to serialize that instance, along with the SparkContext it holds

One possible solution would be removing `mwToMap` from the `EsContext` class (**possibly into a companion object** of `EsContext` - objects need not be serializable as they are static). If there are other methods of the same nature (`write`?) they'll have to be moved too. This would look something like:

```
import EsContext._

class EsContext(sparkConf:HadoopConfig) extends SparkBase {
   private val sc = createSCLocal("ElasticContext", sparkConf)

   def documentsAsJson(esConf: HadoopConfig): RDD[String] = { /* unchanged */ }
   def documents(esConf: HadoopConfig): RDD[EsDocument] = { /* unchanged */ }
   def shutdown() = sc.stop()
}

object EsContext {
   private def mwToMap(mw: MapWritable): Map[String, String] = { ... }
}
```

If moving these methods out isn't possible (i.e. if they require some of `EsContext`'s members) - then consider separating the class that does the actual mapping from this context (which seems to be some kind of wrapper around the SparkContext - if that's what it is, that's *all* that it should be).

Comment: I added the complete files [here](https://github.com/apanimesh061/elastic-spark). You can have a look if you want

Comment: I copied your code - still can't make it compile, I guess there are some version differences... Anyway, I did what I could, hope it helps, take it or leave it :)

Comment: `write` is a function from `org.json4s.native`. So would it make any difference?

Comment: probably not - as it's a static fuction. I'll remove it from the answer

Comment: Since, you said that you were unable to run the code. I'll update that with the POM file that I used. May be you could try it whenever you have the time.

Comment: I might, not sure. Did you try my suggestion at all?

Comment: Yes, I was getting symbol not found for `mwToMap`. I updated the whole project [here](https://github.com/apanimesh061/SparkTest).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105953/discussion-between-tzach-zohar-and-animesh-pandey).